# How to control the order in which elements float on window resize, inside a table

Tags: html

So I have these tables that I'm trying to make for an email template, and these three columns which have a float property in order to stack them one bellow another when I resize the window.

The thing is that while it looks good at maximum size and minimum size (at maximum they are next to each other, at minimum they are one bellow another, as intended), in between the third column moves below the first while the second remains next to the first, and after further resizing the second column then changes it's position below the first column and the third column moves further away from the second one. What I wish to know is if there is a way to make them move in a certain order, like the first one to move below should be the second column, and only after that the third. Or even better would be if they moved all at once!

Also, I am very curious as to why are the texts moving upward inside the cells when I give them the float property, me preferring them to remain vertically aligned in the center, as they were before making them float.

Note: because this is intended for emails, I had to use all my css styling inline as the server I use does not recognize the style tag. Also the max width for the table is of 600px

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="placeholder" style="width: 180px;float:left;">
Description:
</td>
<td class="links" style="width: 275px; float:left;">
<a href="#" target="_blank">very long link</a>
</td>
<td class="buttons" style="width: 85px; float:left;">
<a href="#" target="_blank" "="">button</a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose table cell item (placeholder, links and buttons) in a different Html.

See/try the following code:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="width:180px;display:inline-block" class="placeholder">Description:</div>
          <div style="display:inline-block">
            <div style="width:275px;display:inline-block" class="links"><a href="#" target="_blank">very long link</a></div>
            <div style="width=85px;display:inline-block" class="buttons"><a href="#" target="_blank" "="">button</a></div>
          </div>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Items are in one table cell, so the table has one column, with the same width.

The description item is enclosed in div with display:inline-block.
Both links and buttons are enclosed in another div with display:inline-block.

When You resize window the second div (that enclose links and buttons) wrap and take links and buttons togheter on the second row.

If the table has more columns you need to enclose all columns in that way.

Comment: it worked perfectly, thank you very much for helping me with this!